# Friendly way to show MalformedCSVError to non-english speakers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I want provide as much feedback as possible to users trying to import data from `csv`. The problem is on the cases I need to rescue `CSV::MalformedCSVError` because the exception message is in english(I can't use english) and there is no other way to distinguish one error from another.
What can I do to show the exact problem to the user?

Comment: What internationalization (I18n) framework are you using? Some of them you can plug in a phrase like "Error Invalid X" and it will resolve to the equivalent in another language if you've created that translation.

Comment: @tadman I'm using Rails default I18n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you tagged this as Rails so that means you have I18n. Why don't you do something like the following:

`begin
 # csv parsing code
rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError => ex
  raise(CSV::MalformedCSVError.new(I18n.t("csv_parser.malformed_csv_error"))
end`

Note: this does assume CSV::MalformedCSVError inherits from StandardError which might not be the case but you get the idea, raise an exception and set the message to some translated I18n string.

UPDATE:

If you wanted even more detail you could match against the exception message and have translations for each message type, while capturing the data you want from the error message string - for instance line number etc. I have no idea right now what the error messages look like but say you have something like "error in column 45" then you could do the following

```
begin
 # csv import code
rescue CSV::MalformedCSVError => ex
  err_message = case ex.message
  when /column (\d+)/
    I18n.t("csv_error.column_error_message", column: Regexp.last_match[1])
  else
    I18n.t("csv_error.generic_message")
  end
  raise(CSV::MalformedCSVError.new(err_message))
end
```

Comment: This way I will lose the message to know what error caused the exception.

Comment: @Doguita you could log the actual error an raise the translated one that way you can see what happened in English and the end user can see it in the translated language.Just for edification purposes `CSV::MalformedCSVError` inherits from `RuntimeError` which in turn inherits from `StandardError`

Comment: @engineersmnky I agree it´s a way but I will wait a little more to check other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE: The GEM

I've taken this monkey patch and turned it into a gem. Check it out, along with a test suite:

https://github.com/jhubert/csv-i18n

---

### Original Answer

I bumped into this problem and decided that unless I was ok with showing unhelpful error messages to my users, I could go with two options:

1. Introduce a new class like FriendlyCSV that wrapped the CSV parser, examined the exception message and returned a relevant error message in the right language.
2. Monkey-patch the CSV library to return translated error messages.

The first way is probably the proper way to go, since I control the source code and can use whatever class I want to process the incoming CSV files.

However, I'm far too reckless for that and I liked the idea that ANY CSV parsing done anywhere in the system returned translated messages, without other people needing to be aware of the `FriendlyCSV` class.

So, I went with #2.

### The Monkey Patch

You can find the patch here:
https://gist.github.com/jhubert/7d75586857d41fb4c45c4491363636e9

The core behavior is that we're overwriting the `shift` method, which is where the bulk of the string parsing is. We're attempting to translate the error message and then returning the original exception.

```
  def shift
    super
  rescue ::CSV::MalformedCSVError => exception
    raise $!, translated_exception_message(exception.message), $!.backtrace
  end
```

Hope that helps!